# I am trying to avoid implementing loops in this code block. What are some data types that could be a good alternative instead of loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables, object

What would be the best way to rewrite this JavaScript counter function without loops?

```
var superCounter = function(str) {
    var counterObj = {};
    counterObj.spaces = 0;
    counterObj.words = str.split(' ').length;
    str.split('').forEach(function(e) {
        if(e === ' ') {
            counterObj.spaces += 1;
        }
    });
    counterObj.chars = str.length;
    return counterObj;
}; 
console.log(superCounter("Count me in"));
```

Comment: `counterObj.spaces = str.split(' ').length-1;` Or `counterObj.spaces = counterObj.words-1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regular expressions where applicable:

```js
var superCounter = function(str) {
  var spacesRegex = new RegExp(/\s/g);
  var wordsRegex = new RegExp(/\S+/g);
  return counterObj = {
    spaces: spacesRegex.test(str) ? str.match(spacesRegex).length : 0,
    words: wordsRegex.test(str) ? str.match(wordsRegex).length : 0,
    chars: str.length
  };
};
console.log(superCounter("Count me in ok?"));
```

Note this is not the most performant solution out there.